# How can I fix a 'can't create dynamic relocation' error when building an open-source C/C++ debugger extension with CMake?

Tags: c, cmake

Open source C/C++ debugger extension build from source.

so I tried https://github.com/vadimcn/codelldb debugger.

Here I am facing an issue while doing the build.

```
[100%] Linking C shared library libcodelldb.so ld.lld: error: can't create dynamic relocation R_X86_64_32 against symbol: typeinfo for std::bad_alloc in readonly segment; recompile object files with -fPIC or pass '-Wl,-z,notext' to allow text relocations in the output
>>> defined in /usr/lib/llvm-10/bin/../lib/libc++abi.a(stdlib_exception.cpp.o)
>>> referenced by new.cpp.o:(std::__throw_bad_alloc()) in archive /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libc++.a
```

these below steps that I have followed to build

```
git clone https://github.com/vadimcn/codelldb.git
cd codelldb
export CC=/usr/bin/clang
export CXX=/usr/bin/clang++
mkdir build
cd build 
npm cache clean --force
cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=cmake/toolchain-x86_64-linux-gnu.cmake -DLLDB_PACKAGE=/home/aximsoft/lldb.zip
make
```

Comment: The build procedure in the package's build instructions at https://github.com/vadimcn/codelldb/blob/master/BUILDING.md don't look much like the procedure you describe.  If those instructions do not work then you are probably best off seeking support from the project maintainers.

Comment: we have posted the question in  their GitHub "Discussions". But no responses.
https://github.com/vadimcn/codelldb/discussions/946